# Why does stmfd/ldmfd jump back to sub?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am doing a project for UNI and have a problem.

We are learning how to push/pop registers onto stack when calling a subroutine.

I need to write a subroutine to convert a decimal number 0-15 into a corresponding hex ASCII code, and keep the value of all registers except `r0`, where the result should be stored. I have a table of ASCII codes, and basically just add the `number*4` to the starting address of the ASCII table, and store the value back into `r0`.

I get the right result, but the subroutine loops. It keeps jumping from `ldmfd` to `sub` endlessly. Any idea why?

```
main:
adr r0,num
adr r1,ascii
ldr r2,[r0]
bl  sub
sub:  stmfd sp!,{r1-r2,lr}
      ldr r0,[r1,r2,LSL #2]
      ldmfd sp!,{r1-r2,pc}

/* variables here */
num:    .word 15
ascii:  .word 0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x46
/* end variables */
```

Comment: It may make things clearer for you if you restructure you code to have the subroutine before main in the assembly file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. The main code never returns anywhere, which means after your code returns from the sub it will start again at "sub:" because thats your return point. As lr did not change, it will be stuck in a loop between stmfd/ldmfd. You need to call the exit-function of your system.
2. There is no reason to save r1, r2, lr. You're not changing them in your code, also r0-r3 and r12 are caller saved registers anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Note that you have placed your subroutine directly following the instruction that calls it:

```
bl  sub
sub:  stmfd sp!,{r1-r2,lr}
      ldr r0,[r1,r2,LSL #2]
      ldmfd sp!,{r1-r2,pc}
```

So what happens when you return from the first call to `sub`? It will return to the instruction following the `bl`, i.e. the `stmfd sp!,{r1-r2,lr}`. So the subroutine effectively returns to the beginning of itself. And it will keep doing so because there are no additional implicit or explicit writes to `lr`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no ARM assembly expert, but I can at least read some local compiler output.

It seems gcc prefers not to store `lr` on the stack (which makes sense, the point of the register is to *avoid* stack access when possible).

Instead, subroutines end by doing a branch on the link register:

```
bx  lr
```

Note: it seems the `bx` (branch exchange) instruction is only available on Thumb-capable processors, so perhaps it doesn't apply for you then.

Comment: GCC isn't relevant to the question and neither is the availability of 'BX LR' since the question is about returning with an LDM.

Comment: @PeteFordham I see your point, but [unwind](http://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) is just pointing out an in-efficiency.  There are many in the posted assembler.  I resisted pointing these out.  However, the `STM/LDM` pair are completely un-needed and actually **unwind** is correct; even though he may not know why.  **Michael** got my vote as he answered the main part of the question.  Compiler writers are smart people; ignore them at your peril.

Comment: In case that wasn't clear, `bx lr` is an alternative to the `ldmfd sp!,{...,pc}` in this case.  There is no need to save `r1-r2` that are passed in to the routine and not modified.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I understand that I am not changing any register values, and therefore the stmfd and ldmfd are reduntant, it is more of an exercise on how to deal with calling subroutines and exiting from them, and not so much writing optimized code. I guess optimizations come later in the course :-) Thanks anyway for all your answers, you have been very helpful!